# Converting BitSet to Byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, bitset

I have a BitSet, which needs to be converted to a Byte[]. However, by using BitSet.toByteArray(), I don't get the correct output. I have tried converting the Byte[] to its binary form in order to check whether the Bitset and the binary form of the Byte[] are similiar.

```
public static void generate() {

        BitSet temp1 = new BitSet(64);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            if(i % 8 != 0 && i < 23) {
            temp1.set(i, true);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            s.append(temp1.get(i) == true ? 1 : 0);
        }

        System.out.println(s);

        byte[] tempByteKey1 = temp1.toByteArray();

        for (byte b : tempByteKey1) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(b & 255 | 256).substring(1));
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
Bitset: 0111111101111111011111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Converted Byte: 1111111011111110011111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

They are both 64 bits, but the first 0 in the BitSet is placed somewhere else after the conversion. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: the bit order is being printed in reverse by `toBinaryString` as you are printing the BitSet. You start with the less significant bit, `toBinaryString` starts with the most significant one.(see how the zero is in first position on first output, and at 8th position on second output)

Comment: But they both have six trues as low order and seven trues as high order

Comment: what are you counting??? BitSet: `01111111 01111111 01111110 0...`; toBinaryString: `11111110 11111110 01111110 0...` => each corresponding 8 bits are reversed. Or, using chars for bits, BitSet: `hgfedcba ponmlkji ...` , toBinaryString: `abcdefgh ijklmnop ...`

Comment: That makes sense, but is it possible to store it as it originally was i.e. without the reversing?

Comment: ??? it is stored as originally , just the way you represent it differs as how `toBinaryString` does

Comment: "don't `== true`" :)

Answer (score 1):

From [BitSet#toByteArray() javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html):

> Returns a new byte array containing all the bits in this bit set.
>   More precisely, if..

```
byte[] bytes = s.toByteArray();
```

> then

```
bytes.length == (s.length()+7)/8
```

> and

```
s.get(n) == ((bytes[n/8] & (1<<(n%8))) != 0)
```

> for all `n < 8 * bytes.length`.
>
> @return a byte array containing a little-endian representation of all the bits in this bit set
>
> @since 1.7

**Attention:** `toByteArray()` doesn't even claim to know `size()`, it is only "reliable" regarding `length()`!

---

..So I would propose as implementation (alternative for your `toBinaryString()`) a method like:

```
static String toBinaryString(byte[] barr, int size) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 8 * barr.length; i++) {
        sb.append(((barr[i / 8] & (1 << (i % 8))) != 0) ? '1' : '0');
    }
    for (; i < size; i++) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

..to call it like:

```
System.out.println(toBinaryString(bitSet.toByteArray(), 64);
```

---

```
run:
0111111101111111011111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0111111101111111011111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```