# Converting a BitSet to a byte[] with same representation

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bitset

I am working on generating a 64 bits keys for DES where only 20 bits are effective i.e. the rest is padded with zeros. The way I am trying to approach it is by having a `BitSet` of 23 bits where every 8th is skipped (i.e. kept as false) and the rest is determined the `SecureRandom.nextBoolean()`. So, the output of my BitSet is 23 bits where every 8th is false. The reason why I do this is to make sure that the parity bits are not a part of the 20 bits effective key. 
Afterwards, I try to convert the `BitSet` by using `Bitset.toByteArray()`, which gives me 3 bytes and then I pad the rest 5 bytes with zeros. However, the problem occurs when I try to convert the `BitSet` to a `byte[]` as the representation is reversed.

```
public static byte[] generateDesKey() {
        BitSet temp = new BitSet();
        byte[] zeroByteKey = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        Random r = new SecureRandom();

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            if (i % 8 != 0 && i < 23) {

                temp.set(i, r.nextBoolean());
            }
        }

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for( int i = 0; i < temp.length();  i++ )
          {
              sb.append( temp.get( i ) == true ? 1: 0 );
          }

          System.out.println("Bitset " +sb );

        byte[] tempByteKey = temp.toByteArray();

        for (byte b : tempByteKey) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(b & 255 | 256).substring(1));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tempByteKey.length; i++) {
            zeroByteKey[i] = tempByteKey[i];
        }

        return zeroByteKey;
    }
```

An example of output:

```
Bitset 00010100011110010011101 // 23 bits where parity bits are skipped
Converted BitSet to byte[] in binary 101101000000111001011100 // 24 bits where every 8 bits are reversed
```

The reason why, I assume, the second output is 24 bits is because 23 bits is rounded up to 3 bytes, when converted from `BitSet` to `byte[]`.

Comment: please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53402433/592355)